# Prefetch_related in Django views results in surplus database queries

Tags: django, django-orm

I have blown my mind trying to figure what I am doing wrong in this code:

```
contacts = Contact.objects.user(request.user).prefetch_related(
                        Prefetch('contact_phone',
                                 queryset = ContactPhone.objects.order_by('value')))

    for contact in contacts:
        for contact_phone in contact.contact_phone.all():
            # do something
```

Django hits database several times. Any ideas ? Can it be that I can use prefetch_related in Django templates, and in views it hits database several times ???

For 10 contacts I have 10 database hits, each one looking like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM `contact_phone` WHERE `contact_phone`.`contact_id` = ...
ORDER BY `contact_phone`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

So, there seems to be two unclear things to me. First, why does Django hit the database for each contact. And second, why does it limit phone number to 1 record ?

The respecive model looks like this:

```
class ContactPhone(BaseMixin):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, models.CASCADE, related_name = 'contact_phone')
```

Comment: What is `# do something`? What is `user(request.user)?` I'm not sure that you're showing enough code to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You get one query per `Contact` because in the `prefetch_related` you sort by `value`, while in the iteration you don't sort by any attribute. If the executed query doesn't match the prefetched one, a new query is done.

See the note at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related:

> Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained
>   methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously
>   cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.

To avoid extra database queries do:

```
contacts = Contact.objects.user(request.user).prefetch_related(
                        Prefetch('contact_phone',
                                 queryset = ContactPhone.objects.order_by('value')))

    for contact in contacts:
        for contact_phone in contact.contact_phone.order_by('value'):
            # do something
```